# Iso of constant sheaf and stalk

Tags: sheaf-theory

Say i am given the sheaf:

\begin{eqnarray*}
M_X: {{Op}_X}^{op} & \longrightarrow & \text{Mod}(k)\\
U & \longmapsto & M_X(U) := \lbrace f: U \longrightarrow M \mid \forall_{x \in U }\exists_{V \in I_x}:f\mid_V = \text{const} \rbrace
\end{eqnarray*}

which is called the constant sheaf with values in the category of modules.

I need to show the following:

Every stalk of $M_X$ is isomorphic to $M$:

Can someone show me the proof in terms of inj/surj ?

Comment: well, the point is that i dont know which morphism i should take to show inj\surj.

Comment: Finding this morphism is certainly where you need to start. I'll give you an hint : take $\operatorname{ev}_x:M_X(U)\rightarrow M, f\mapsto f(x)$. Show that this morphism pass to the limit. Hence you have $\operatorname{ev}_x:M_{X,x}\rightarrow M$. Show that this last morphism is an isomorphism. (For this you can try to construct a morphism in the other direction)

Comment: what do you mean by "passing to the limit" ?

Comment: The stalk $M_{X,x}$ is the inductive limit of the $M_X(U)$ for $U\ni x$. You need to use the universal property of the limit to define a morphism $M_{X,x}\rightarrow M$, and this is what I call "passing to the limit".

Comment: So the UP is $M_X(U_i) \rightarrow lim_{x \in U}M_X(U) \rightarrow_{\exists} M$? but isn't i clear that i have the surj. $f \mapsto f_x$? or am i thinking in the wrong direction?

Comment: Yes the morphism $f\mapsto f(x)$ is clearly surjective. (You see, I want you to try something, to write parts of the proof. And now you have done that ! Try to prove it is also into, maybe you will manage to do this, and if you don't I will help you where you are stuck)

Comment: ok i think i will just write in an answere what i got an then you could comment, what is wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Proof:

Let $U$ be a nbh of $x \in X$ and 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi_{U,x} : M_X(U) & \longrightarrow & M\\
f & \longmapsto & \phi_{U,x}(f) := f(x)
\end{eqnarray*}
be the evaluating map (k-module homomorphism). We have to show, that the evaluating map
\begin{eqnarray*}
(M_X)_x & \longrightarrow & M\\
f_x & \longmapsto & f(x)
\end{eqnarray*}
is an isomorphism.

Inj.: Let $f(x) = 0$. It ex. a nbh $V$ of $x$ such that 
$f\mid_V = 0$. because $f$ is locally constant. That induces that the germ is 0.

Surj.: For $m \in M$ choose $f_x$ the constant section
\begin{eqnarray*}
f: X & \longrightarrow &M\\
p & \longmapsto & f(p) := m
\end{eqnarray*}
for all $p \in X$. So obv the  $f_x$ is $m$.

Comment: Yep that's it. But to be complete, you need to prove that $(M_X)_x\rightarrow M$ is well defined. That is why you have introduce the $\phi_{U,x}$ above : to use the universal property.

Comment: Also, be careful with the notations. $f_x$ should be the germ at $x$ of the function $f$. For example, at the end, you should write : let $f_x$ be the germ of the constant section $f:p\mapsto m$. Then obviously, $\phi_x(f_x)=m$.

Comment: and i guess that is the point which i dont understand.

Comment: So what is your definition of the stalk $\mathcal{F}_x$ ?

Comment: $\mathcal{F}_x := lim_{x \in U} \mathcal{F}(U)$

Comment: See : inductive limit, so you need to use the universal property. Here, you just need to say that the $\phi_{U,x}$ are compatible with the restrictions maps. Or if you have already showed that $(M_X)_x$ is the set of pairs $(f,U)$ with $f\in M_X(U)$ up to a suitable equivalence, you need to show that the evaluation map does not depends on a representative (this is the universal property of the quotient).

Comment: So to make things clear:

I just have to add to the above proof at the end the fact, that the morphism $(M_X)_x \rightarrow M$ is -well defined- but that follows from the fact, that the ev. morphism $\phi_{U_i,x} = \phi_{U_j,x} \circ \rho_{ij}$ for an open inclusion $U_j \hookrightarrow U_i$?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: q.e.d? well then thank you very much :) ! ! !

Comment: Yes you have all the arguments ! I encourage you to complete the proof above, and correct some details/notations, I will upvote your answer then. Does the proof seems fine to you ? Or is there still some points that you have accepted because I said it was ok ? It should be clear to you ! Finally, I encourage you to write your attempts in your future questions. Maybe you will realize that you are able to answer your own questions as you did for this one ! Or maybe you will miss a little argument, and people will help you with it instead of the whole proof.